# Build an array from yaml in rails

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, yaml, twilio

I'm working on a simple rails app that does SMS.  I am leveraging Twilio for this via the twilio_ruby gem.  I have 10 different phone numbers that I want to be able to send SMS from randomly.

I know if I do something like this:

```
numbers = ["281-555-1212", "821-442-2222", "810-440-2293"]
numbers.sample
281-555-1212
```

It will randomly pull one of the values from the array, which is exactly what I want.  The problem is I don't want to hardcode all 10 of these numbers into the app or commit them to version control.

So I'm listing them in yaml (secrets.yml) along with my Twilio SID/Token.  How can I build an array out of the 10 yaml fields i.e. twilio_num_1, twilio_num_2, etc, etc so that I can call `numbers.sample`?

Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use

```
twilio_numbers:
  - 281-555-1122
  - 817-444-2222
  - 802-333-2222
```

thus you don't have to write the numbers in one line.

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out through trial and error.

In secrets.yml

`twilio_numbers: ["281-555-1122","817-444-2222","802-333-2222"]`

In my code:

`Rails.application.secrets.twilio_numbers.sample`

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

create a file: `config/twilio_numbers.yml`

```
---
  - 281-555-1122
  - 817-444-2222
  - 802-333-2222
```

and load it in your `config/application.rb` like this:

```
 config.twilio_numbers = YAML.load_file 'config/twilio_numbers.yml'
```

you can then access the array from inside any file like this:

```
 Rails.application.config.twilio_numbers
 => ["281-555-1122", "817-444-2222", "802-333-2222"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm doing something similar but in secrets.yml instead of config.  One less file to have to track outside of version control :)